# get minutes and seconds of current time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need minutes and seconds of current time.

```
var d = new Date();
var e = d.getMinutes();
var f = d.getSeconds();
```

Errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: d.getMinutes is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: d.getSeconds is not a function
```

Any help?

Comment: that should work

Comment: Was `Date` overwritten?

Comment: @pushkin, yes it was, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as written works:

```js
var d = new Date();
var e = d.getMinutes();
var f = d.getSeconds();
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = e + ' minutes and ' + f + ' seconds';
```

```html
<div id="result"/>
```